# Vitest - Passed prop `onUserAdd` function is not invoked when submited from

Tags: reactjs, testing, vite, vitest

I'm new to testing with Vite and attempted a basic example to learn. However, I'm facing an issue where the function passed to UserForm is not getting called during testing. I'm simulating user inputs, but when I check the result, it shows an error saying 'AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once.'

**App.jsx**

```
import './App.css';
import UserForm from './components/UserForm';
import UserList from './components/UserList';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const[userList, setUserList] = useState([]);

  const onUserAdd = (user) => {
    setUserList([...userList, user]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <UserForm onUserAdd={onUserAdd} />
      <hr />
      <UserList userList={userList} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**UserForm.jsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

const UserForm = ({onUserAdd}) => {
 
  const[user, setUser] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
  })

  const handleEmptyInput = () => {
    setUser({
      name: '',
      email: '',
    })
  }

  // input change
  const handleNewUser = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;

    setUser({...user, [name]: value});   
  }

  // submit form
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(user.name && user.email) {
            
      onUserAdd(user);
      handleEmptyInput();
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input         
          type="text" 
          name="name"
          id="name"
          value={user.name}
          onChange={handleNewUser}
          />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input          
          type="email" 
          name="email"
          id="email"
          value={user.email}
          onChange={handleNewUser}  
        />
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Add User</button>
    </form>
  )
}

UserForm.defaultProps = {
  onUserAdd: () => {}
}

UserForm.propTypes = {
  onUserAdd: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default UserForm;
```

**UserForm.test.jsx**

```
import { test, describe, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import user from '@testing-library/user-event';
import UserForm from '../components/UserForm';     

// User from 
describe('User Form', () => {    

  test('it invoke onUserAdd when the form is submitted', async ()=> {    
   
    const mock = vi.fn();     
      
    render(<UserForm onUserAdd={mock} />);

    const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');                          

    user.click(nameInput); 
    user.keyboard('Martin'); 
    
   
    user.click(emailInput); 
    user.keyboard('martin@gmail.com');     
   
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');    
   
    await user.click(button); 
  
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();        
   
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({name: 'Martin', email: 'martin@gmail.com'});

  })

})
```